# Kickstart Round C 2020 Countdown Problem - finding number of contiguous subarray

Tags: python, arrays

Edit - The output didn't have a space before the colon. But after changing that, instead of wrong answer, it's saying runtime error. Even the sample input tests ran successfully. What could possible be wrong?

Problem
Avery has an array of N positive integers. The i-th integer of the array is Ai.

A contiguous subarray is an m-countdown if it is of length m and contains the integers m, m-1, m-2, ..., 2, 1 in that order. For example, [3, 2, 1] is a 3-countdown.

Can you help Avery count the number of K-countdowns in her array?

Input
The first line of the input gives the number of test cases, T. T test cases follow. Each test case begins with a line containing the integers N and K. The second line contains N integers. The i-th integer is Ai.

Output
For each test case, output one line containing Case #x: y, where x is the test case number (starting from 1) and y is the number of K-countdowns in her array.

Limits
Time limit: 20 seconds per test set.
Memory limit: 1GB.
1 ≤ T ≤ 100.
2 ≤ K ≤ N.
1 ≤ Ai ≤ 2 × 105, for all i.

Test set 1
2 ≤ N ≤ 1000.

Test set 2
2 ≤ N ≤ 2 × 105 for at most 10 test cases.
For the remaining cases, 2 ≤ N ≤ 1000.

Sample

Input

3
12 3
1 2 3 7 9 3 2 1 8 3 2 1
4 2
101 100 99 98
9 6
100 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 100

Output

Case #1: 2
Case #2: 0
Case #3: 1

```
T = int(input())

res = []
for i in range(T):
    N, K = map(int, input().split(' '))
    ai = list(map(int, input().split(' ')))
    y=0
    count=0
    for m in range(len(ai)):
        count=0
        if(ai[m]==K):
            if(len(ai)>=m+K-1):
                    for j in reversed(range(1, K)):
                        if(ai[m+K-j]==j):
                            count=count+1
                    if(count==K-1):
                        y=y+1
            else:
                break
        else:
            continue
    res.append("Case #"+str(i+1)+" : "+str(y))
for g in range(len(res)):
    print(res[g])
```

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  Your posted code hangs, waiting for input.  "Wrong answer" is not a problem specification.  Your attempts to trace the problem do not appear in this post.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/4785185/prune , on google kickstart, it doesn't show which test case failed. So, even I am unaware of where the intermediate results deviated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a two-pointer approach like take two variables `i` and `j` and initialize both with 0

Keeping `i` fixed increment `j` if the required condition is met i.e.

```
while(a[k+1]-a[k]==1):
    j++
    k++
```

wherever condition fails, calculate `j-i`. If at all `j-i==m` then increment your counter say `cnt` and then put `i=j` and repeat until the end of array